# Magento 2 : jQuery Tokenizer Ui Component Edit Form

Tags: magento-2.1, forms, jquery, uicomponent

The new style of M2 Ui forms using knockout Js has changed many things we do with M1 .
My Jquery Tokenizer **does not** dispaly tokens in **edit** form, tokens are added successful when we create new token. Below is the code files if someone could figure out.My console displays the error : **ReferenceError: tag_names is not defined**

## Tags Js

```
define([
'ko',
'jquery',
'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
'jquerytokenize'
], function (ko, $, Abstract) {
'use strict';


function updateValue(viewModel, value) {

    viewModel.value(value);
}

ko.bindingHandlers.myTags = {


    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        // document.write(JSON.stringify(element.value));

        if (valueAccessor()) {
            $('#' + element.id).tokenize({


                onAddToken: function (value, text, tokenize) {
                    updateValue(viewModel, tokenize.select.val());
                },


                onRemoveToken: function (value, tokenize) {
                    updateValue(viewModel, tokenize.select.val());
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
return Abstract.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Namespace_Module::/form/element/tags.html'
     }
    });
});
```

## Tags Html

```
<select multiple class="admin__control-multiselect" data-bind="
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    id: uid,        
    disabled: disabled,
    'aria-describedby': noticeId,
    placeholder: placeholder
},

hasFocus: focused,   
selectedOptions: value,
optionsValue: 'label',
optionsText: 'label',
myTags: true"
 />
```

## Ui Form Field

```
<field name="tag_names">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">   
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module/js/tags</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>

                <!-- <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item> -->

                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module/form/element/tags</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Article Tags</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">article</item>                   
            </item>
        </argument>
```

Note: The format of the token's field data is same as it was during the save .

Comment: Replace template with  template: 'Namespace_Module/form/element/tags'

Comment: @Rakesh  My console shows the error  ReferenceError: tag_names is not defined